# nodejs request memory leak error when submitting multiple requests

Tags: javascript, node.js

So let me describe the problem I'm solving here. I need to iterate over an array and fire off an http GET request for each item in the array. As you can see below I'm iterating over `list`, constructing the url on each iteration and firing off the request.

Now I understand that request is making these calls async but there has to be a way to slow the loop down. I tried setTimeout but that doesn't seem to affect it. I have about 350 items in the array and need 350+ requests. I was doing these by hand but need to automate this.

```
_.each(list, function (item) {
  var url = 'https://google.com/search?tbm=nws&q='+query+" "+item;

  request(url, function (err, resp, body) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var
      dom = cheerio.load(body),
      headlines = [];

    dom('.r').each(function () {
      var headline = dom(this).text();

      if (headlines.join(' ').length < 450) {
        headlines.push(headline);
      }
    });

    q.resolve(headlines.join(' '));
  });
});
```

**Error**

> (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners()
>   to increase limit.

Comment: If you want to slow it down, then you shouldn't be using `_.each` or `for` or anything that iterates the `list` all at once. You should do one in a function, then use a `setTimeout` that does the next by incrementing an `i` can calling the same function, which again does another `setTimeout` and so on until `i` is equal to the length of the list.

Comment: ...or do it without `setTimeout` and do the next one when the previous is complete. You can do a few at a time as well if desired.

Answer (score 1):

try the async module https://github.com/caolan/async:

the code you can use is this:

```
var async = require("async");
var request = require("request");
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
async.forEachLimit(list,1,function(item,callback){
    var url = 'https://google.com/search?tbm=nws&q='+query+" "+item;
    request(url, function (err, resp, body) {
        if (err) throw err;

        var
           dom = cheerio.load(body),
           headlines = [];

        dom('.r').each(function () {
            var headline = dom(this).text();

            if (headlines.join(' ').length < 450) {
                headlines.push(headline);
            }

         });

         q.resolve(headlines.join(' '));

         callback();

      });

 },function(err){
  if(err)console.log(err);return;
});
```

no need for setTimeout
this is perfect for async calls
Thanks